# Characterizing the type input for which a given method gives the best results

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have $m$ input examples each described by a set of **numerical** features. To each example I apply $k$ methods and pick the best one according to a certain performance measure. Thus my data looks as follows, where 'BestMethod' is the dependent variable (nominal):

Feature1, Feature2, ..., BestMethod

What I want is to characterize the type of input for which a given method is the best. Is there any statistical method/test that can be used in this case?

Thanks,

Comment: Is that not a classification problem? Classifying which method is the best given some input? I'm an expert in machine learning hence I phrase it as a question.

Comment: @JesperHybel To be honest, this has similarities with classification, but classifiers are used for prediction, and this is not my goal. What I want is to state (with statistical evidence) that method A, for example, gives better results on such and such input .